# MySQL: How to associate a column alias with a specific JOIN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

My query pulls results from several tables using a few `LEFT JOIN`s. It currently works fine. However, I now have to get two different fields from the same table column (but matching different conditions). I don't know how to make sure the correct column alias gets assigned from the correct LEFT JOIN. Make sense?

So here's for example...

```
SELECT table1.user_id, table2.value AS school, table2.value AS language  FROM table1  
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = table1.user_id AND table2.key = 'school'
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = table1.user_id AND table2.key = 'language'
```

I need the column aliases with the corresponding `JOIN`. How do I do this?

For reference, here is my original query (without secondary JOIN):

```
SELECT wsat_ib.user_id, wpjb_resume.id resume_id, wpjb_resume.firstname, wpjb_resume.lastname, 
     wsat_ib.overall_score, wsat_ib.account_score, wsat_ib.econ_score, wsat_ib.math_score,
     wsat_ib.logic_score, wsat_ib.fsanaly_score, wsat_ib.corpval_score, wsat_ib.end_time, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wp_usermeta.meta_value) AS target_employers, wpjb_field_value.value AS school, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(wpjb_application.job_id) AS applications FROM  `wsat_ib` 
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON wsat_ib.user_id = wp_usermeta.user_id
    LEFT JOIN wpjb_resume ON wsat_ib.user_id = wpjb_resume.user_id
    LEFT JOIN wpjb_field_value ON wpjb_resume.id=wpjb_field_value.job_id AND wpjb_field_value.field_id=3
    LEFT JOIN wpjb_application ON wpjb_application.user_id = wsat_ib.user_id 
    WHERE (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'target_employer' AND (wp_usermeta.meta_value = 'public' OR wp_usermeta.meta_value=1523) AND wpjb_resume.is_active =1) AND (wpjb_resume.firstname='Xu' OR wpjb_resume.lastname='Xu') 
    GROUP BY wsat_ib.user_id, resume_id, wpjb_resume.firstname, wpjb_resume.lastname, wsat_ib.overall_score, wsat_ib.account_score, wsat_ib.econ_score, wsat_ib.math_score, wsat_ib.logic_score, wsat_ib.fsanaly_score, wsat_ib.corpval_score, wsat_ib.end_time, wpjb_field_value.value
     ORDER BY overall_score DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Here's my early attempt at implementing the solutions below. I've added the `AS school` to the JOIN clause, but have not yet added the second JOIN for that table. For some reason, this version returns no results.

```
SELECT wsat_ib.user_id, wpjb_resume.id resume_id, wpjb_resume.firstname, wpjb_resume.lastname, 
 wsat_ib.overall_score, wsat_ib.account_score, wsat_ib.econ_score, wsat_ib.math_score,
 wsat_ib.logic_score, wsat_ib.fsanaly_score, wsat_ib.corpval_score, wsat_ib.end_time, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wp_usermeta.meta_value) AS target_employers, wpjb_field_value.value AS school, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(wpjb_application.job_id) AS applications FROM  `wsat_ib` 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON wsat_ib.user_id = wp_usermeta.user_id
LEFT JOIN wpjb_resume ON wsat_ib.user_id = wpjb_resume.user_id
LEFT JOIN wpjb_field_value AS school ON wpjb_resume.id=wpjb_field_value.job_id AND wpjb_field_value.field_id=3
LEFT JOIN wpjb_application ON wpjb_application.user_id = wsat_ib.user_id 
WHERE (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'target_employer' AND (wp_usermeta.meta_value = 'public' OR wp_usermeta.meta_value=1523) AND wpjb_resume.is_active =1) AND (wpjb_resume.firstname='Xu' OR wpjb_resume.lastname='Xu') 
GROUP BY wsat_ib.user_id, resume_id, wpjb_resume.firstname, wpjb_resume.lastname, wsat_ib.overall_score, wsat_ib.account_score, wsat_ib.econ_score, wsat_ib.math_score, wsat_ib.logic_score, wsat_ib.fsanaly_score, wsat_ib.corpval_score, wsat_ib.end_time, wpjb_field_value.value
 ORDER BY overall_score DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to alias the tables as well, not just the columns.

```
SELECT table1.user_id, schools.value AS school, languages.value AS language
FROM table1  
LEFT JOIN table2 AS schools ON schools.user_id = table1.user_id
    AND schools.key = 'school'
LEFT JOIN table2 AS languages ON languages.user_id = table1.user_id
    AND languages.key = 'language'
```

If a table appears more than once in a query, you can think of each appearance kind of as an instance. You need to name each instance of the table to disambiguate them.

Comment: Thanks. I commented to @Andomar above that for some reason the query isn't returning any results when I add the alias to the table in the JOIN. I've included my query above. Do you see anything in it that would prevent this from working as expected?

Comment: @Emerson yes, you aren't giving aliases to the table instances in the top example query. In the bottom query with wordpress tables, I don't see any tables that are joined twice, so don't see how this is relevant. Which table are you supposedly joining twice?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. That was my original query before making the modification. I'll add the new query (that isn't working) now...

Comment: I dug deeper and it appears to be a problem in the syntax (not a zero result): `WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'wpjb_field_value.value' in 'field list']`

Comment: @Emerson that's because you aliased the `wpjb_field_value` table to `school`. So the field is `school.value`, not `wpjb_field_value.value`. Look at the query in my answer for an example.

Comment: AHA! That did it. So after aliasing the column in the `JOIN LEFT` it should be referenced by the alias everywhere else (even in the SELECT above) except for the WHERE clause. Is that right?

Comment: @Emerson only partially right. It should reference the alias everywhere, including the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3):

```
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t2.id = ...
                ^^^^^^^
```

The `as` can be omitted, as in:

```
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = ...
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Just out of curiosity, is it normal to do what I'm attempting by JOINING the same table multiple times? Is there a better way to do it that I'm missing?

Comment: It's perfectly normal for an EAV design (entity-attribute-value)  EAV in itself is not undisputed though.

Comment: Thanks! That's reassuring. But I'm having some trouble, when I add the `AS school` to the corresponding `LEFT JOIN` in my query, I get no results. I've tried it both with and without the original `AS school` in the select clause. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?