# mysql join aliases same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a music catalogue with recordings.  Each recording has an owner an an author.  The tables are:

```
recordings
recordings_authors(Fk rec_id, Fk contact_id)
recordings_owners(Fk rec_id, Fk contact_id)
contacts (name of people)
```

The final echo will show:

```
Title: (name of title)
Author: (name from contacts)
Owner: (name from contacts)
```

The following works fine, except Owner shows as the same contact as Author. Removing the JOIN author entirely still brings up the error.

```
SELECT recordings.title,contactsauthors.name AS authorname,contactsowners.name AS ownername
FROM recordings

JOIN recordings_authors AS authors ON recordings.id=authors.rec_id
JOIN contacts AS contactsauthors ON authors.rec_id=contactsauthors.id

JOIN recordings_owners AS owners ON recordings.id=owners.rec_id 
JOIN contacts AS contactsowners ON owners.rec_id=contactsowners.id

WHERE recordings.id=1


$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
echo $row['title'].'<h2>Credits</h2>Author: '.$row['authorname'].'<br>Owner: '.$row['ownername'];
```

The best answer I could find here is this one
[MySQL: How to associate a column alias with a specific JOIN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183817/mysql-how-to-associate-a-column-alias-with-a-specific-join-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong key in your contact joins. You should use `contact_id` instead of `rec_id`:

```
SELECT recordings.title,contactsauthors.name AS authorname,contactsowners.name AS ownername

FROM recordings

JOIN recordings_authors AS authors ON recordings.id=authors.rec_id 
JOIN contacts AS contactsauthors ON authors.contact_id=contactsauthors.id
-- here ----------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^

JOIN recordings_owners AS owners ON recordings.id=owners.rec_id 
JOIN contacts AS contactsowners ON owners.contact_id=contactsowners.id
-- here --------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^

WHERE recordings.id=1
```

Comment: Many thanks chue x, this worked perfectly.  Indeed it was only the contact_id that was incorrect.